# Convert [Byte]? to [Byte]

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm new to swift and I'm trying to decode an array of bytes being sent back to me in form [Byte]? and when i try and use

```
if let string = String(bytes: d, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(string)
} else {
    print("not a valid UTF-8 sequence")
}
```

It says it needs to be unwrapped. I can't change the base code which is returning the optional array as it is getting returned from a framework.

Comment: `if let bytes = d, let string = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8) {}`? Or since, you are beginning, in a more explicit way: `if let bytes = d { if let string = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8) {} }`

Comment: Cheers, looked about but didn't know what I was really searching for. tried using flatMap which confused me.

Comment: You'd use a `flatMap()` if it was `[Byte?]`, meaning that each element of the array if an optional. But you have `[Byte]?` meaning that the array is optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `guard let`

```
guard let unwrappedBytes = d else { return }
```

With this you will get the exact same data as before, but without the question mark.

I know it's pretty hard to understand the optional thingy in Swift. I would recommend to checkout the Apple Docs, which are pretty good:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional

Comment: First you hate optionals, then you can't live without :)

Answer (score -3):

[Byte]? means this is a optional array. ? is the symbol of option here.

Optional variables may have value or not, mean its the possibility values is retuned by the variable is null. Read from ref link: https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-an-optional-in-swift

Change your code to:

```
if let string = String(bytes: d!, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(string)
            } else {
                print("not a valid UTF-8 sequence")
            }
}
```

I have placed a symbol ! with d. This is way of optional unwrapping in swift.

Comment: Using exclamation mark is not recommended, because this could lead to an app crash when the optional is nil.

Comment: Yes I agree with you Ling. But I just explained a one way to unwrap the values. Safe unwrapping is more useful to prevent the crashes.